# How to configure ports of JMeter(Master-Slave) to firewall

Tags: java, performance, testing, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Good day!
Hi I'm doing distributed testing using JMeter and came up with this confusion.
If in case I don't want to disable my firewall, I have to specify the ports needed instead to my firewall. But the thing is, I'm getting confused with the documentation and some tutorials online for their terms such as "server" and "client" and where to apply the configurations to their respective jmeter.properties files. It would have been easy if they  used the term "master" and "slave".
For instance, I'm confused where to change these ports. Is it for the "master server" or  "slave servers"

> If you're running JMeter in distributed mode you need to open the following ports:
> the port you define as server_port, by default 1099
> the port you define as server.rmi.localport
> the ports you define as client.rmi.localport

Please if you have any links or documentations about these configuration let me know to enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `server` == `slave`
- `client` == `master`

You need to open:

1. `1099` or whatever is your `server_port`
2. the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
3. the port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- you may also be interested in [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) which contains comprehensive steps on configuring/exposing ports in the network in order to establish JMeter master/slaves connectivity.